# Button not linking properly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason this button is not linking correctly. could someone please show me what Im doing wrong?

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="<%= @most_popular %> btn btn-default"><%= link_to "Most Popular", posts_path %></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_to` creates an anchor tag. [Reference.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

Nesting anchor tag inside a button is not correct HTML afaik. If you want your link to look like a button you can try this. Bootstrap happily accepts all button classes on anchor tags.

```
<%= link_to 'Most Popular', posts_path, :class => "btn btn-default #{@most_popular}" %>
```